# Bifascicular Block In Young Male Asymptomatic Patient

Tags: cardiology, asymptomatic

An asymptomatic 25 year old male presents with an ECG pattern of bifasicular conduction block (left anterior hemi-block and right bundle branch block) after experiencing "extra/skipped beats".

The patient has no remarkable family or past medical history.

What are the potential causes of the bifasicular block in a male patient of this age and what tests should be done to differentiate these causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person is well, and investigations show no structural defects, then:

> Early-onset cardiac conduction defects in the absence of structural heart disease should prompt consideration of CCD genetic testing, especially if a positive family history of conduction abnormalities and pacemaker implants is identified.

[HRS/EHRA Expert Consensus Statement on the State of Genetic Testing for the Channelopathies and Cardiomyopathies](http://m.europace.oxfordjournals.org/content/13/8/1077.long?view=long&pmid=21810866)

Some other causes not age specific some of which are listed [here](http://lifeinthefastlane.com/ecg-library/basics/bifascicular-block/) include ischemic heart disease, cardiomyopathies, hypertension, aortic stenosis, Lev’s disease, hyperkalemia, congenital heart disease, sarcoid cardiomyopathy, Chagas disease, and scleroderma.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful.  What about when there is no family history?

Comment: Could be new mutation. But the point of genetic testing is to make sure no one else is affected

Comment: it could also be non-genetic, e.g. chagas disease, sarcoidosis maybe others?

Comment: Yes, but you said the patient was well.

Comment: Yes, but by well I meant asymptomatic.  Chagas and primary sarcoidosis of the heart can often be asymptomatic.

Comment: In that case you need to establish an underlying disease condition of which conduction disorders may be a manifestation.  But the question as worded appears to state the patient is well, with no significant medical history and presumably nothing else to find on examination.

Comment: yes a well patient with no findings on physical examination may well have chagas or primary sarcoidosis.  What other underlying diseases might the patient have that lead to conduction disorders?